# how to FT.SEARCH nested JSON on redis

Tags: redis

i'am new on redis... i want ask
how to use FT.SEARCH on my redis db to get some field on JSON nested object

```
"{\"specs\":{\"material\":\"aluminium\",\"weight\":\"10\"},\"brand\":\"Velorim\",\"model\":\"Jigger\",\"price\":270,\"description\":\"Small and powerful, the Jigger is the best ride for the smallest of tikes! This is the tiniest kids\xe2\x80\x99 pedal bike on the market available without a coaster brake, the Jigger is the vehicle of choice for the rare tenacious little rider raring to go.\",\"condition\":\"new\"}"
```

> i try with this way
>
> ```
> FT.SEARCH idx:sepeda "@specs.weight:{10}
> FT.SEARCH idx:sepeda "@specs.weight:10
> ```

but got an error

```
"Syntax error at offset 7 near weight"
```

what i have to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an index. Please see [documentation](https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/indexing/#create-index-with-json-schema)

For example, for numeric weights,

```
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.CREATE idx ON JSON SCHEMA '$.specs.weight' as weight NUMERIC
```

With a document such as

```
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.SET doc:1 $ "{\"specs\":{\"material\":\"aluminium\",\"weight\":10},\"brand\":\"Velorim\",\"model\":\"Jigger\",\"price\":270,\"description\":\"Small and powerful, the Jigger is the best ride for the smallest of tikes! This is the tiniest kids\xe2\x80\x99 pedal bike on the market available without a coaster brake, the Jigger is the vehicle of choice for the rare tenacious little rider raring to go.\",\"condition\":\"new\"}"
```

You can search for specific weights, such as in the range of 10 to 15 (inclusive)

```
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.SEARCH idx '@weight:[10 15]' NOCONTENT
1) (integer) 1
2) "doc:1"
```

Comment: alhamdulillah, it work bro @oshadmi. thanks